# Track Down Ruby-on-Rails "RunTimeError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, discourse, ruby-3.1

I am new to this Ruby-on-Rails stuff and cannot figure out who to resolve this "RunTimeError"

When I run the following command from `/var/www/discourse`,

```
sudo -u www-data RAILS_ENV=production $ruby_path/bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
```

...part way through the run, I get the following errors lines...

```
MiniRacer::RuntimeError: Error: Could not find module `discourse/lib/utilities` imported from `(require)`
JavaScript at missingModule (<anonymous>:247:11)
JavaScript at findModule (<anonymous>:258:7)
JavaScript at requireModule (<anonymous>:24:15)
JavaScript at <anonymous>:26:11
/var/www/discourse/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/mini_racer-0.6.3/lib/mini_racer.rb:228:in `eval_unsafe'
...
```

Mini_racer **is** installed.

`discourse/lib/utilities` is NOT listed in the source code. [Click here to view Github source code](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/tree/main/lib)

Note: Yes, I know that the official way to run Discourse is with Docker. I am trying to figure out how Ruby-on-Rails pieces fall together and Discourse is what I am fiddling with.

Here is the `rvm info` output...

```
admin@rortest:/var/www/discourse$ rvm info

ruby-3.1.3:

  system:
    uname:        "Linux rortest 5.10.0-20-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.158-2 (2022-12-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    name:         "Debian"
    version:      "11"
    architecture: "x86_64"
    bash:         "/usr/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:          " => not installed"
    remote_path:  "debian/11/x86_64"

  rvm:
    version:      "1.29.12 (latest)"
    updated:      "1 hour 11 minutes 18 seconds ago"
    path:         "/usr/local/rvm"
    autolibs:     "[4] Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies, install package manager (only OS X)."

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "3.1.3p185"
    date:         "2022-11-24"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2022-11-24 revision 1a6b16756e"
    full_version: "ruby 3.1.3p185 (2022-11-24 revision 1a6b16756e) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.3"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.3/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.3/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.3/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.3/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.3"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.3/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but you may find [this](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/c43068720f5f63b4dd433443d7ad9840beef8791/lib/pretty_text/shims.js#L26) and [this](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/c43068720f5f63b4dd433443d7ad9840beef8791/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/app/routes/login.js#L2) helpful in your troubleshooting. I assume you're following some kind of guide or walkthrough? If so I'd retrace my steps to make sure you're not missing something. And this is tagged `ruby-on-rails-3` -- is it really Rails 3? The repo shows Rails 7.

Comment: I fixed the tags, it is clearly Ruby 3, not Rails 3